# starts_with in presto?

Tags: sql, presto

I am new to writing sql queries in presto and was looking for a function similar to 'starts_with'.
If a string starts with a given substring then the query needs to return that record.
In Postgresql, I am currently doing `select * from tableA where name~'^Joh'`. Whats the equivalent of this in Presto?

Comment: Why a regex? `like 'Joh%'` would do the same

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL and presto are RDBMS based on SQL. It is weird to see that you've learned a PostgreSQL proprietary add on (regular expressions) to the language before learning the standard SQL functions. In SQL you use `LIKE` for pattern matches:

```
select * from tableA where name like 'Joh%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Like in SQL. You can go through this link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp. Using like you can search for a specified pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In presto you can use [regexp_like](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html)() which runs little faster than other like operators.For your case try below query which should provide you with expected functionality.

```
select regexp_like('John', '^John')
```